# Can't properly align DIVs with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a website and have been struggling with CSS (I had originally accomplished my goal with JavaScript, but I was having many cross-browser-compatibility issues).

I have 4 `ul`s in a footer which I want to align based upon the screen size.

I set their width properly based on the screen size:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1281px){/*lg*/

    /*sm*/
    .cmc-grid-sm-1 {
        width: 8.33333%;
    }
. . .
```

Yet it appears to be the wrapping of the elements within the parent container which I am having a problem with.

What I would like them to look like is this:
[image: Desired Alignment]

And instead, they end up looking like this:
[image: Undesired Alignment]

**I've highlighted the borders of the elements with red to show how they are aligning**

What can I add to my CSS to make these DIVs align they way I would like them to (I've been looking everywhere for my answer!)?

**[Here is my JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/6k33sky5/)**

Comment: Try using min-height

Comment: Because Contact div doesn't have height.

Comment: Looks like you need to be searching for an `equal height` solution.

Comment: Hahahaha! Wow! That worked! Ooh, thats funny. Thanks guys! **[Here's the updated Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/6k33sky5/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Now i know this is a little bit of a dirty hack and it wont cover every possibility but give this a try out:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 482px) and (max-width: 1024px){

    ...

    .cmc-column:nth-child(3n+3) {
        clear:left;
    }

    ...

}
```

It works in your current situation but dont hold me to it when it comes to adding more columns etc.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k33sky5/2/)

It works as the 3rd div then expects to have nothing to its left pushing it to the left and putting it below the other 2 divs.

Comment: Yeah its really dirty hack. @WebWanderer please avoid it or atleast take it as last solution.

Comment: Hate using dirty hacks but without the full spec/css/how its generated its hard to really specify haha.

Comment: Hey @Stewartside The only reason that you don't have the "full spec/css/how its generated" is because the blocks of CSS that make up my `@media screen` queries are extremely lengthy. The only thing being controlled by these queries is the `width` property, so just ignore them. If you want to view the rest, you can just follow the link to the JSFiddle that I provided (all of the CSS to be concerned with is at the top). As for answering the question, someone already gave me a great solution through a comment, and it simply required me to place a `min-height` property on the `cmc-grid-pos` class

Comment: That's fine I saw later on. Sorta rushed it. Good work on fixing it as I saw above 

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `display: table;` for the container and the `display: table-cell;` or the `display: table-row;` for your inner divs:

```
.container {
  display: table;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Take a look at [the example here](http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/) and apply it to your code.

Comment: I had an issue with this and trying to place all of my `divs` in a single row. The answers been solved though, yet someone posted the solution as a comment, not an answer. I just needed a `min-height`

Comment: Ok I see what you mean but you have to choose the right value to this min-weigth and in the case of display: table in your cmc-grid-posclass it will be arranged automatically

Comment: True, and I'm not the biggest fan to restricting the height, but my list is not being constructed dynamically and will not be changing anytime soon.